# Shiny: Merge cells in DT::datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to merge few rows in column in DT::datatable in shiny. Is it possible to do so?

Currently I am able to output which looks something like this:

[image]

But ideally I would like to merge the rows and want to output something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to merge rows like this in DT::datatable?

Comment: According to @yihue you cannot merge cells in datatables: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/346

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible with the help of the [datatables-rowsgroup library](https://github.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup). Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dat <- iris[c(1,2,3,51,52,53,101,102,103), c(5,1,2,3,4)]

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    dtable <- datatable(dat, rownames = FALSE, 
                        options = list(
                          rowsGroup = list(0) # merge cells of column 1
                        ))
    path <- "U:/Data/shiny/DT/www" # folder containing dataTables.rowsGroup.js
    dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
      "RowsGroup", "2.0.0", 
      path, script = "dataTables.rowsGroup.js")
    dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
    dtable
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution! Maybe adding this plugin in DT library would be a great feature, or maybe create an entirely new R library for DT plugins?

Comment: As a non-Javascript user, I have trouble following your advice. Could you clarify what I need to do between landing on the page you link to and including the code you suggest?

Comment: @NBE Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028528/merge-columns-in-dtdatatable

Comment: This has been really helpful, though I was wondering if it's possible to tweak rowGroup so as to use two columns to merge duplicate cells?

Comment: How to use rowsGroup with rowGroup. i.e. GROUP 1, GROUP 2, rowsGroup

Comment: when you say "# folder containing dataTables.rowsGroup.js" what's that js file? where do I get it?

Answer (score 3):

hey as far as i know its not possible to do it in DT i have another way to make it happen.

```
 kable(c, align = "c") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left",font_size = 12)%>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1, valign = "middle")
```

please try it and it works :)

Comment: install. Packages('kableExtra')