# Merge columns in DT::datatable

Tags: r, dt

I need to merge cells across columns in a DT::datatable in shiny. The best way seems to make use of the Javascript DataTables extension [RowGroup](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/). But I don't know which steps to take from viewing the page in above link, to having merged cells in my shiny app (there's a *reason* I'm working in shiny ;).

There's a partial answer in the accepted answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484118/shiny-merge-cells-in-dtdatatable/56481354#56481354) but 1) that was about merging *rows* (i.e. vertically in stead of horizontally), and 2) the mechanics behind the interaction of R and Javascript seem to be assumed as prior knowledge, leaving me with questions like "which files do I need to download from where" and "do I need to adapt the Javascript code in them?"

Here is a simplified example of my app:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

tbl <- data.frame("A"=c("foo", 1L, "question"),
                  "B"=c("bar", 2L, "answer"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(tbl, rownames=F, class="",
              options = list(autoWidth=T,
                             columnDefs = list(list(className="dt-center", targets="_all"),
                                               list(width="40px", target="_all"))))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In which I'd like to go from this

[image: current table]

to this

[image: table with headers mergedtwo]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may work for you, using `htmltools`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

tbl <- data.frame("A" = c( 1L, "question"),
                  "B" = c( 2L, "answer"))

container_dt= withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      th(class = 'dt-center',colspan = 2, 'AB')),
      tr(
      lapply((c('foo', 'bar')), th)))))
     

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderDT({
        datatable(tbl, container = container_dt, rownames = F, class = "",
              options = list(autoWidth = T,
                             columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"),
                                               list(width = "40px", targets = "_all"))))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Much better than digging through Javascript tutorials! Accept and +1

Comment: Follow-up question: I should have included in my example a column preceding the columns I gave, which I'd like to leave intact. Is that possible?

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me this error `Warning: Error in : options$columnDefs must be `NULL` or a list of sub-lists, where each sub-list must contain a `targets` element.`. I have R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23), htmltools v0.5.3,  shiny v1.7.2. and DT v0.23. So something has changed and now it doesn't work in 2022..

Comment: @emr2 you need to change the second sublist in `columnDefs` from `target` to `targets`. I will update.