# Merge cells horizontally with datatable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, row, dt

I would like to merge cells horizontally (merge 2 columns) on one row.

Minimum, reproducible example:

```
datatable(data.frame('A' = c('a', 1),
                     'B' = c('bc', 2),
                     'C' = c('', 3),
                     'D' = c('de', 4),
                     'E' = c('', 5)))
```

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Is the row with merged cells intended to be part of a header (where header is two rows)? Or are they data that are separate from the header?

Comment: They are data that are separate from the header! Thank you Ben

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be more helpful here. I have seen other SO answers using `htmltools` to have headers span multiple columns with `datatable` (providing a container) such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030740/3460670)...but not sure about your situation as described.

Comment: Thanks, yes I saw that but I don't know how to apply it to my case :(

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is one option to do that:

```
> data.frame(
+   'A' = c('a', 1),
+   'B' = c('bc', 2),
+   'C' = c('', 3),
+   'D' = c('de', 4),
+   'E' = c('', 5)
+ ) |> 
+   rowwise() |> 
+   mutate(C = B, E = D)
# A tibble: 2 × 5
# Rowwise: 
  A     B     C     D     E    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     bc    bc    de    de   
2 1     2     2     4     4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I want to do, I really want to change the display!