# Divide cell into more in a DT::datatable()

Tags: r, dt

Is it posible to divide a cell of a `DT::datatable` into 3 in the same row?Something like:
[image]

```
Population<-"Population 1"
Variable<-c("row1","row2","row3")
df<-data.frame(Population,Variable)
```

Comment: No, but you can merge some cells instead; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481354/1100107

Comment: very useful indeed

Comment: I came into this issue though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482510/the-datatables-rowsgroup-js-reverses-the-order-of-the-merged-column-of-my-datafr

Comment: a relevant here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547393/aggregate-column-values-based-on-other-column-and-merge-the-results-in-one-row-i