# The dataTables.rowsGroup.js reverses the order of the merged column of my dataframe

Tags: r, dt

I have used `dataTables.rowsGroup.js` to merge the 1st column of my dataset but while it is merged succesfully it displays `Population 6` first instead of `Population 1`. How could I reverse it to normal?

```
library(DT)
Population<-c("Population 1","Population 1","Population 1","Population 2","Population 2","Population 2","Population 3","Population 3",
                "Population 4","Population 4","Population 5","Population 5","Population 5","Population 6","Population 6","Population 6")
  Variable<-c("row 1","row 2 to 10","total","row 1","row 2 to 10","total","row 1","total","row 1","total","row 1","row 2 to 5","total","row 1","row 2 to 5","total")
  df<-data.frame(Population,Variable)
  df$Population <- factor(df$Population, levels = c("Population 1","Population 2","Population 3","Population 4","Population 5","Population 6"))
  
  
  
    dtable <- datatable(df, rownames = FALSE,
                        options = list(
                          rowsGroup = list(0) # merge cells of column 1
                        ))
    path <- "C:/Users/User/Documents/Darya/www"
    dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
      "RowsGroup", "2.0.0",
      path, script = "dataTables.rowsGroup.js")
    dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
    dtable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
options=list(order = list(list(1, 'asc'))
```

did it

Comment: But this option sorts the column, no? If so, that wouldn't work if your column were not alphabetically ordered. That looks like a bug.